# How to change the "About" window in my Java program for Mac OS X?

Tags: java, macos, netbeans, about-box

Mac OS X has built in function to show an "About" window.
On my program I can see the name of my head class and "version 1.0".

Where can I change this information? I am using NetBeans and there is nothing related to this setting I can find.

Comment: Too few details. btw How Java is related to your problem?

Comment: I use NetBeans to build my program in java.

Comment: I think there's a .property file somewhere that contains the information

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The place(s) to set these items is described in http://developer.apple.com/library/mac/#documentation/Java/Conceptual/Java14Development/07-NativePlatformIntegration/NativePlatformIntegration.html.

It is not difficult, but it isn't easy.

You can change the name that appears in the about dialog by editing your project's Run properties... the 'VM Options' property, specifically.  You would add something like "-Xdock:name=BLAHBlahblah" to that property's text field.  Your project will appear with thename BLAHBlahblah in the menubar AND the About dialog that opens when you select 'BLAHBlahblah->About BLAHBlahblah'

You can change the icon by applying the VM option -Xdock:icon, too.